# SBT custom task hangs

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, onejar, sbt-onejar

I have the following custom `taskKey` in my `built.sbt`:

(it's my first attempt at defining a custom SBT task, so beware of stupidities)

```
lazy val makeDeployJar = taskKey[java.io.File](
  "Runs 'package', collects all the sub-project JARs in the lib folder of the root project, and runs 'one-jar'")

makeDeployJar := {
  val jars = List(
    (Keys.`package` in Compile in root).value,
    (Keys.`package` in Compile in common).value
    (Keys.`package` in Compile in core).value,
    (Keys.`package` in Compile in analysisProj).value,
    (Keys.`package` in Compile in ui).value
  )
  // looks like OneJar operates on JARs in the lib folder only, so need to collect all JARs
  // and temporarily copy them to lib and delete them later:
  val libDir = (baseDirectory in root).value / "lib"
  val libPaths = jars.map(libDir / _.getName)
  IO.copy(jars zip libPaths)
  val oneJarOutput = oneJar.value
  IO.delete(libPaths)
  // move the resulting JAR to a more human friendly location
  val finalPath = (baseDirectory in root).value / "profile.jar"
  IO.copyFile(oneJarOutput, finalPath)
  // this is the tedious SBT way of logging
  streams.value.log.info(finalPath.toString)
  // return the resulting JAR path for completeness' sake
  finalPath
}
```

Convoluted though it is, it runs fine and produces the result I'm after.

However, when I add the following to my `built.sbt`:

```
artifactName in ThisBuild := {
  (_: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
  artifact.name + "-" + module.revision + "." + artifact.extension
}
```

whenever I run the `makeDeployJar` task, it hangs indefinitely after outputing:

```
...
[info] Compiling 16 Scala sources and 3 Java sources to /myproj/ui/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Packaging /myproj/target/scala-2.10/myproj-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /myproj/target/scala-2.10/myproj-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
```

SBT is a complicated beast, and I'm new to SBT—am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in SBT?

Comment: Why do you need to move those `package` jars? OneJar should take them from what they are anyway. As far as I understand it takes from `lib` just unmanaged dependencies.

Comment: @laughedelic: I assumed so as well but it seems OneJar is not taking them from the subproject `target` directories; otherwise I wouldn't have written this task.

Comment: Does the root project aggregate these subprojects? If the dependencies are set correctly, you won't need this task. Anyway your `build.sbt` would be useful.

Comment: @laughedelic: http://pastebin.com/qV0bUF2A